# How to create Mortal Kombat game in c#?

Tags: c#, xna

Where do I start for this game?

I do have xna studio. But I do not know the flow to create such a good game.

***EDIT::***

I do have a good hands on c#/asp.net development. I am totally new for game development.

Ok, i appreciate your answers/comments, but can you tell me which studio is the best for c# game development, or where do i start to do game development.

Comment: Anything large is made up of smaller components. Plan out small things, and implement them. I suggest you get started on something much easier (stick figure combat) and move on from there. One step at a time. Good luck.

Comment: This is a terrible question. It is not specific. Please read the FAQ.

Comment: why closed? whats wrong.. if anything wrong you can edit the question in a good way. that will help to me also..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Start small!

Here are some tutorials to get you started : http://einfall.blogspot.com/

Believe me when I say, a path of a game developer starts with the easiest of games:

1. Write your own [Tetris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetris)
2. Write your own [Arkanoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arkanoid)
3. Write your own [Mario](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mario)-like
4. Write your best game, and the fame will be yours.

If you don't fail on step 1, glamorous future might await you. If you start with Mortal Kombat, you'll fail miserably.

Comment: As an indie game developer the worst thing you can do is attempt to make the latest blockbuster hit on your own. The key is starting small, learn to walk before you run.

Answer (score 3):

Well I'd say the best thing to do is to start simple. It may sound like the boring way to get going but you'll learn a lot by writing small compartmentalized bits of code than diving into such a large project. One of the most common problems with projects that you're not getting paid for is finding the motivation to finish them. If you create small bits of functionality you'll be able to see how far along you're getting. And if you think about the design of each bit of functionality before you start typing away you'll be able to plug them together to start your game going.

I'd recommend doing something like getting a sprite (image) on screen that can be moved around first. Then try making it "jump" when a button or key is pressed. Once you've got this mastered you could start adding inertia and physics to it, or if you fancy a break leave that bit alone for the moment and start creating life gauges that are displayed on the top of the screen and that you can show being depleted.

If you're new to programming in general then perhaps a gaming framework would be the best place to get started. There are quite a few around and you'll see much faster progress albeit trading in complete control.

Good luck